# Invalid protocol : null error while installing through NPM on windows 10

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules, npm-start

I'm getting

> Invalid protocol : null

error when I'm trying to install any packages using NPM in windows 10.

[image]

Comment: Did you execute the -g option in a command shell with admin priviliges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me also was having same problem.. I think problem with the OS, just try to reinstall OS this will solve your problem